# Unable to npm install in a node docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /frontend/

ENV PATH /frontend/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /frontend/package.json
COPY . /frontend/
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

This is my `Dockerfile` for the frontend of my project.

I put this as one of the services in my `docker-compose.yml` file, and when I run `docker-compose up -d --build`, it gives me

```
Step 6/8 : RUN npm install --silent
 ---> Running in 09a4f59a96fa
ERROR: Service 'frontend' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --silent' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My docker-compose file looks like below for your reference:

```
# Docker Compose
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - '.:/frontend'
      - '/frontend/node_modules'
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
       - .:/code
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT: Error in the frontend after build**

[image]

Comment: Try to remove --silent to see what's happending when you install your node packages

Comment: @ToanQuocHo Thanks. I removed the `--silent` and the build worked. However, when I `docker-compose up` after the build, the backend successfully goes up, but my frontend gives me an error as shown in my EDIT. I have no idea why it cannot find the package.

Comment: Try to change `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]` to `CMD ls && pwd` to double check that your code is there and package.json also there

Comment: @ToanQuocHo Thanks. I found the issue and fixed it. I really appreciate it. By the way, I am new to `docker-compose` and I wonder if I have to `docker-compose up -d --build` every time before I do `docker-compose up`?

Comment: Not really, you just need to run `--build` whenever you want to rebuild your images, that mean only when you make a change on your Dockfile then run with `--build` to create a new image. Btw, please write an answer for your question cause that might help other people who facing the same issue like yours

Answer (score 0):

For docker-compose, I think it should be like

```
- ./frontend/:/frontend'
```

as the build context is frontend.

Second, thing if you are using volume then why you are installing and copying code in Dockerfile? If you are using bind volume then remove these from your Dockerfile as these will be overridden from the host code.

```
COPY package.json /frontend/package.json
COPY . /frontend/
```

Comment: I am new to Docker and I don't understand what `volumes` are. Are you saying that the `COPY` that I used is redundant?

Comment: yes exactly, the copy is good for `production` image and volumes is good for development. your bind volume to the same directory will override every thing inside your docker image.

Comment: So shall I just remove the first line?

Comment: if you are intended to use in production then remove from docker-compose both volume line, if you are using in development then remove both line in dockerfile related to copy.

Comment: also, make sure the context `- ./frontend/:/frontend'` in volume, that is why pacakge.json is not here

Comment: What exactly is a volume and what does `./frontend/:/frontend'` this syntax mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200284/discussion-between-adiii-and-dawn17).